# How to prove $F_{n-1}F_{n-2}-F_nF_{n-3}=(-1)^n$, where $F_n$ is nth fibonacci number?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I'm struggling to prove the following equation:
$$
F_{n-1}F_{n-2}-F_nF_{n-3}=(-1)^n
$$
You can verify this fact with [this python code](https://www.online-python.com/eoQcrP9K1x).

I managed to simplify the equation a little, so that only $F_{n-2}$ and $F_{n-3}$ left:
$$
(F_{n-2})^2-F_{n-2}F_{n-3}-(F_{n-3})^2=(-1)^n
$$
But I still don't see how to prove that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, how does the bot have permission to close based off of my single close vote? I would have thought at least two votes would be needed, to double-check

Comment: @FShrike: “Community” here means that the author of the question confirmed it as a duplicate.

Comment: To the op: Before you look at the linked post, I recommend you attempt some induction first. If you get stuck with the induction, you can find the answer in the linked post (and probably many other places on the internet)

Comment: @MartinR Ah, thanks for clarifying

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities